# target framework doesn't show the '.NET Core 3.1' In 'visual studio'

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, c#-4.0

I use serenity framework that it needs to '.NET Core 3.1', I've installed

Visual Studio 2019 SDK and Runtime  for '.NET Core 3.1'  and I've checked the version with this command :

```
dotnet --version
```

that's show 3.1.401.
but I still couldn't see .NET Core 3.1 in the target framework.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only way to get it to show up is to update Visual Studio.

You can do this by opening Visual Studio clicking `Help` > `Check for Updates`.

In my case, I had to change my `global.json` file in the root project folder to:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.1.0",
    "rollForward": "latestFeature"
  }
}
```